# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

After adding this code:

```
<?php
    foreach($emp as $empdata){
    echo "<tr><td>".$empdata[emp_id]."</td><td>"."<a href="?>edit.php?emp_id=<?php echo $empdata[emp_id] ">".$empdata[emp_name]."</a></td></tr>";
    } ?>
```

I get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/kumar/public_html/amsConcrete/single_pages/employee/show_employee.php on line 23
```

Any suggestions? Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something went a little funny in the middle of your output:

```
$empdata[emp_id]."</td><td><a href='edit.php?emp_id=".$empdata[emp_id]."'>".$empdata[emp_name]."</a></td></tr>";
```

I think this should do the trick though.

You don't need to run echo inside the string (in fact it's a bad thing). You can however just use the variables as they are - which you did for part of it, but not the other part.

Comment: @RC Yeah, noticed (and fixed that) and also got rid of a silly looking concat that served no purpose as well. Cheers!

Comment: What about array keys without quotes? They are constants or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It should be work

```
<?php
    foreach($emp as $empdata){
    echo "<tr><td>".$empdata[emp_id]."</td><td><a href='edit.php?emp_id=". $empdata[emp_id]. "'>".$empdata[emp_name]."</a></td></tr>";
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is more easier format 
<?php
    foreach($emp as $empdata){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $empdata['emp_id'] ?></td>
        <td><a href='edit.php?emp_id=<?php echo $empdata["emp_id"] ?>'><?php echo $empdata['emp_name'] ?></a></td>
    </tr>    

<?php  } ?>
```